# Best way of sorting a groupby expression when taking first row

Tags: python-polars

I would like to group a dataframe by "foo", and take the first value of the *sorted* group.

I have one solution, but it involves sorting the entire dataframe, where I believe it would be much faster to sort within the groups. There would be more instances of sort, but the size `n` of each group is much smaller, and sorting performs as `n*log(n)`.

```py
df = pl.DataFrame({"foo": [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3], "bar": [5, 7, 6, 4, 2, 3, 1]})

df_desired = pl.DataFrame({"foo": [1, 2, 3], "bar": [5, 2, 1]})

df_solution = df.sort("bar").groupby("foo", maintain_order=True).first().sort(by="foo")

assert df_desired.frame_equal(df_solution)
```

My suggestion would be a method that would sort each group. Does this sort of thing exist?

```py
df_suggestion = df.groupby("foo").<sort_groupby(by="bar")>.first()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:
`df.groupby("foo").agg(pl.col("bar").sort().first()).sort(by="foo")`

Comment: Nailed it! I'd forgotten that all of common methods after `groupby()` are shortcuts into `.agg`!

Comment: does this take the first `row` sorted by `bar` or does it take the first value of only the `column` `bar`?