# Sorting a groupby expression when taking first row, keeping all columns

Tags: python-polars

Given the following dataframe, I would like to group by "foo", sort on "bar", and then keep the whole row.

```py
df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "foo": [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3],
        "bar": [5, 7, 6, 4, 2, 3, 1],
        "baz": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
    }
)

df_desired = pl.DataFrame({"foo": [1, 2, 3], "bar": [5, 2, 1], "baz": [1,5,7]})
```

```py
>>> df_desired
shape: (3, 3)
┌─────┬─────┬─────┐
│ foo ┆ bar ┆ baz │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╡
│ 1   ┆ 5   ┆ 1   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2   ┆ 2   ┆ 5   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3   ┆ 1   ┆ 7   │
└─────┴─────┴─────┘
```

I can do this by sorting beforehand, but this is expensive compared to sorting the group:

```py
df_solution = df.sort("bar").groupby("foo", maintain_order=True).first().sort(by="foo")

assert df_desired.frame_equal(df_solution)
```

I can sort by "foo" in the aggregation, as in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74431467/1018861):

```py
>>> df.groupby("foo").agg(pl.col("bar").sort().first()).sort(by="foo")
shape: (3, 2)
┌─────┬─────┐
│ foo ┆ bar │
│ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═════╡
│ 1   ┆ 5   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2   ┆ 2   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3   ┆ 1   │
└─────┴─────┘
```

but then I only get that column. How do I also keep "baz"'s row value? Any additional entries to `.agg([])` are independent of the new `pl.col("bar").sort()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `.unique()` instead of `.groupby()` after the `.sort()`

```
>>> df.sort(by="bar").unique(subset="foo")
shape: (3, 3)
┌─────┬─────┬─────┐
│ foo ┆ bar ┆ baz │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╡
│ 3   ┆ 1   ┆ 7   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2   ┆ 2   ┆ 5   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1   ┆ 5   ┆ 1   │
└─────┴─────┴─────┘
```

For `.groupby().agg()` you can get the index of the row with `pl.col("bar").arg_min()`

You can pass this to `pl.all().take()` to return all columns.

```
>>> df.groupby("foo").agg(pl.all().take(pl.col("bar").arg_min()))
shape: (3, 3)
┌─────┬─────┬─────┐
│ foo ┆ bar ┆ baz │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╡
│ 3   ┆ 1   ┆ 7   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2   ┆ 2   ┆ 5   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1   ┆ 5   ┆ 1   │
└─────┴─────┴─────┘
```

**UPDATE:**

Can also be written as `.sort_by().first()`

```
>>> df.groupby("foo").agg(pl.all().sort_by("bar").first())
shape: (3, 3)
┌─────┬─────┬─────┐
│ foo ┆ bar ┆ baz │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╡
│ 1   ┆ 5   ┆ 1   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3   ┆ 1   ┆ 7   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2   ┆ 2   ┆ 5   │
└─────┴─────┴─────┘
```

Comment: Yes! I love both suggestions, learnt a lot. The second one appeals the most, since its closest to my original desired solution, but its really interesting that I can take the index like that and pass it to `.take`!